# Removing plot points within a ggplot based on column value within a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to run a function in R that plots the values of a single column in a dataframe against values from several other columns from the same dataframe. The output is several geom_point plots on a single ggplot. However, I would like to remove plot points with certain values from the plots. Specifically some of the dataframes contain 0 values that should not be plotted.

I have tried using subset() in several different formats for this problem however, I normally get errors saying
" Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator"
I have tried simplifying the code and the 0 values are not removed at all!

```
## Plots #------
library(tidyverse) #loads all Hadley verse

x <- c(0,0,3,0,4)
y <- c(2,0,1,2,5)
KeyValue <- c(1,0,2,2,3)
df <- data.frame (x, y, KeyValue)

## Write function for producing graphs
PlotGr <- function(x){
  xplot <- x %>%
    gather(-"KeyValue", key = "var", value = "value") %>%
    ggplot(subset(x,value!==0) + 
    aes(x = value, y = `KeyValue`)) +
    geom_point(alpha=1/4) +  
    facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free") + 
    theme_bw()

  ggsave(filename= paste0(deparse(substitute(x)),'.pdf'))
}

PlotGr(df)
```

To get a PDF output that contains 2 separate plots, with zero values on the y axis removed.

Currently my function is failing and I am completely lost!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try something like:

```
xplot <- 
  x %>%
  gather(-"KeyValue", key = "var", value = "value") %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = `KeyValue`)) +
  ...
```

Comment: Amazing, so simple but really appreciate it thankyou!